# Contrapositive verifications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The contrapositive of:

> The product of an irrational number and a non-zero rational number is irrational.

is:

> If the product of two numbers is rational, then it cannot be the case that one of those numbers is irrational and the other is a non-zero rational number.

And the contrapositive of:

> for any real number $x$, if $x$ is irrational then $\sqrt x$ is not a rational number

is:

> If $\sqrt x$ is rational, then $x$ is rational

And the contrapositive of

> If $x^2$ is even, then $x$ is even

is:

> If $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ is odd

Correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's the spirit. All correct